# adding two columns to vba userform combobox

Tags: excel, vba, combobox

i have that userform for stock control which used to in or out items, all i want to do to amend the below code to show each item name beside it`s code to make searching items.
Code:

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Click()

Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim final As Integer
Dim FINAL2 As Integer

For i = 2 To 1000
    If Hoja5.Cells(i, 1) = "" Then
        final = i - 1
        Exit For
    End If
Next

For i = 2 To 1000
    If Hoja6.Cells(i, 1) = "" Then
        FINAL2 = i - 1
        Exit For
    End If
Next

For i = 2 To final
    If ComboBox1 = Hoja5.Cells(i, 1) Then
        TextBox1 = Hoja5.Cells(i, 2)
        Exit For
    End If
Next

For j = 1 To FINAL2
    If ComboBox1 = Hoja6.Cells(j, 1) Then
        TextBox8 = Hoja6.Cells(j, 3)
        Exit For
    End If
Next

End Sub


Private Sub ComboBox1_Enter()
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim H As Integer
Dim final As Integer
Dim tareas As String

ComboBox1.BackColor = &H80000005

For i = 1 To ComboBox1.ListCount
    ComboBox1.RemoveItem 0
Next i

For j = 2 To 1000
    If Hoja5.Cells(j, 1) = "" Then
        final = j - 1
        Exit For
    End If
Next

For H = 2 To final
    tareas = Hoja5.Cells(H, 1)
    ComboBox1.AddItem (tareas)
Next
'End If

End Sub
```

photo indicating the required amendment

[image: this is the main form to be modified]

I want it to be like:

[image: the result would be like this]

sample file

[download sample for the above userform](https://www.dropbox.com/s/xkmgi666z0p3y3j/stock%20sample.xls?dl=0)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**To do this:**

1. Set the `ColumnCount` = 2 for ComboBox

   [image]
2. Set the 2nd column value by `ComboBox1.Column(1,{rowIndex})` = 'the value'`. In your code. it should be like:

   `For i = 2 To final
        tareas = Hoja5.Cells(i, 1)
        ComboBox1.AddItem (tareas)
        '-- set the first column
        ComboBox1.Column(1, i - 2) = Hoja5.Cells(i, 2) 'the name
    Next`

Comment: @AElsheikh Don't forget to accept his answer.  Not only did he earn it but it closes the question; making it faster for other questions to be answered.

Answer (score 3):

You need to specify the `ColumnCount` value, and provide an array for the `List` property. If you want you can also specify a string containing a comma-separated list of column widths for the `ColumnWidths` property, too:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub PopulateComboBox(ByVal source As Range, Optional ByVal valueColumn As Long = 1, Optional ByVal hasHeader As Boolean = True)
    With Me.ComboBox1
        .ColumnCount = source.Columns.Count
        .ColumnWidths = GetColumnWidths(source)
        .ListWidth = IIf(ComboBox1.Width > source.Width, ComboBox1.Width, source.Width)
        .List = source.Range(source.Rows(IIf(hasHeader, 2, 1)).EntireRow, source.Rows(source.Rows.Count).EntireRow).Value
        .BoundColumn = valueColumn
    End With
End Sub

Private Function GetColumnWidths(ByVal source As Range) As String
    Dim cols As Long
    cols = source.Columns.Count

    Dim widths()
    ReDim widths(1 To cols)
    Dim col As Long
    For col = 1 To cols
        widths(col) = source(, col).Width
    Next
    GetColumnWidths = Join(widths, ",")
End Function
```

Suppose you have a `ListObject` on a worksheet:

[image: Title | Genre; a table with a handful of movies]

The code that works with the `UserForm1` instance is responsible for calling the `PopulateComboBox` method:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test()
    With New UserForm1
        .PopulateComboBox Sheet1.ListObjects(1).Range
        .Show vbModal
    End With
End Sub
```

[image: table contents in a 2-column dropdown]

---

Quite often, you want `ComboBox.Text` to be something user-friendly, and `ComboBox.Value` to be something useful - like some ID value:

[image: Id | Title | Genre]

The problem with doing that is that the `ComboBox` will always use the contents of the first column in its source for display, so you get this:

[image: ComboBox.Text is "1" but selected item is "1 | Lord of the Rings | Adventure"]

The solution is simply to hide the first column (i.e. set its width to `0`):

[image: we have 3 columns, but the first non-zero width column contains user-friendly film titles]

Since `valueColumn` is `1`,  `Me.ComboBox1.BoundColumn` is referring to the hidden ID column, so when we do this:

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_AfterUpdate()
    If Not IsNull(ComboxBox1.Value) Then Debug.Print ComboBox1.Value, ComboBox1.Text
End Sub
```

This is what's printed in the *immediate pane* after selecting *Lord of the Rings*:

```
 1            Lord of the Rings
```

`ComboBox1.Value` is `1`, and `ComboBox1.Text` is `Lord of the Rings`: now the rest of your code doesn't have to deal with string literals!

Comment: That's a pretty cool idea set the column widths using the Products table's column widths.  Along the same lines, maybe you should set the drop list's width using the tables width: ComboBox1.ListWidth = Worksheets("PRODUCT").ListObjects(1).Range.Width

Comment: @ThomasInzina thanks! that's a good idea - but I'd also take the combobox's own width into consideration, it looks weird when the list is narrower than the dropdown itself. How about `.ListWidth = IIf(ComboBox1.Width > source.Width, ComboBox1.Width, source.Width)`? =)

Comment: Thanks for the Kudos.  I was working with your concepts; trying to refine my knowledge of range/table objects in relation to list controls.  I replicated your table and named it movies.   The following is what I came up with:

Comment: `.ColumnHeads = True`
        `.RowSource = "Movies[#Data]"`
        `.ColumnCount = [Movies[#Data]].Columns.Count`
        `.ColumnWidths = Join(Array([Movies[Title]].Width, [Movies[Genre]].Width), ",")`
        `.ListWidth = IIf(.Width > [Movies[#Data]].Width, .Width, [Movies[#Data]].Width)`

Comment: oooh I'm liking this!

Comment: Yeah me too!  Note that by setting the `RowSource` to the table data and the lists `ColumnHeads` to true that the table's headers will show as the headers of the list.

Comment: Ah!! I kept failing to get those darn headers to show up!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123034/discussion-between-thomas-inzina-and-mats-mug).

Answer (score 1):

This code will fill the combobox as well as adjust it's settings to display the your products.  If you use it you will not be able to add or remove items from the combobox.  You will have to edit the actual list on the worksheet.

- `.RowSource = "OFFSET(PRODUCT!$A$1,1,0,COUNTA(PRODUCT!$A:$A)-1,3)"` Links the combobox's list to the a dynamic list on the worksheet.  It will skrink and grow with that list.
- `.ColumnCount = 3`  Sets the Combobox to display 3 Columns
- `.ColumnWidths = "100pt;100pt;200pt"` Sets the width of each column
- `.ListWidth = "400pt"` Sets the width of the drop down.  Which I made bigger then the actual combobox.

[image]

---

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

    With ComboBox1
        .RowSource = "OFFSET(PRODUCT!$A$1,1,0,COUNTA(PRODUCT!$A:$A)-1,3)"
        .ColumnCount = 3
        .ColumnWidths = "100pt;100pt;200pt"
        .ListWidth = "400pt"
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: A little less flexible than my solution, but certainly gets the job done. Kudos for working with OP's file!