# Adding second column to a dynamic rowsource in Excel Userform

Tags: excel, userform, vba

I'm trying to populate a userform with a second column to make it more user-friendly. Currently it shows an ID number, but I also want it to display a name.

I found an answer in this thread ([adding two columns to vba userform combobox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39422101/adding-two-columns-to-vba-userform-combobox)) which seems to do what I want, but I can't quite get the code to match up with mine as I'm using a dynamic reference to populate the combobox, rather than static references.

Here's my attempt at the initialize macro:

```
Dim C As Range
Sheets("Consent_Outcome").Activate
Range("A2", Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).Name = "Dynamic"
Range("L2", Range("L" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).Name = "Dynamic2"
Me.cboURN.RowSource = "Dynamic"

For Each C In cboURN
Me.cboURN.Offset(1, 0) = "Dynamic2"
```

I want it to populate the second column in the combobox with the value from column L, which apparently I should do by setting the 2nd column value as ComboBox1.Column(1,{rowIndex}) = 'the value'`, but I can't get it working with the Dynamic reference. Can anyone suggest how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you've hard-coded "A2" as the top of the range, I gather you are assuming that the data will always start on the second row. If you assign the range `L2` to a range variable, you can use an incremental loop to assign the range variable's value to the appropriate list value, then `.Offset(1,0)` and reassign the range variable to increment down the column.

**Note: My code should work with an excel combobox; I don't know if it'd work for an Access combobox.**

Assuming that `cboURN` is your combobox:

```
Dim C As Range
Dim index as Integer

Sheets("Consent_Outcome").Activate
Range("A2", Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).Name = "Dynamic"
' Unnecessary: Range("L2", Range("L" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).Name = "Dynamic2"
Me.cboURN.RowSource = "Dynamic"

Set C = Range("L2")

With cboURN 'Or Me.cboURN; you can reference named controls without the preceding "Me."
    For index = 0 to .ListCount - 1
        .List(index, 1) = C 'Or C.Value2
        Set C = C.Offset(1,0)
    Next index
End With
```

Alternatively, you should be able to also use this code to populate the combobox (although if you need the items added in a specific order, this option may not be the best):

```
Dim C As Range
Dim cell As Range
Dim index as Integer

Sheets("Consent_Outcome").Activate
Set C = Range("A2", Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))

With cboURN 'Or Me.cboURN; you can reference named controls without the preceding "Me."
    For each cell in C 
        .AddItem cell
        .List(.ListCount - 1, 1) = cell.Offset(0, 11) 'Offset 11 columns to column L
    Next cell
End With
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Would you mind clarifying that? I'm still a novice so I'm not sure I've gotten the hang of loops yet. I've updated my comment above with the code I've tried on your suggestion, but it's not working.

Comment: @stov12 Added. **Additional Notes:** `.Offset([Row],[Column])` is a range property. Comboboxes have "Lists" the items listed as options. Information on these lists can be accessed be `.List([Row],[Column])` or `.List([Row])` (if only one column). Lists are zero-indexed; thus the `.ListCount - 1` to obtain the Row index for the last item.

Comment: Amazing, thank you so much! That worked like a treat.