# How do I perform a total calculation using price in a combo box?

Tags: vba, windows, winforms, helper

I am attempting to make a project on visual studio.

I have the following data in a combo box and I was wondering how I would be able to multiply the price (the `CStr` value) by the number of days the user selects, showing the total in another text box using a calculate button

```
{cmbPedigreeDog.Items.Add("African Hairless" & CStr(1.14))
        cmbPedigreeDog.Items.Add("Boxer" & CStr(0.86))
        cmbPedigreeDog.Items.Add("Chihuahua" & CStr(1.83))
        cmbPedigreeDog.Items.Add("Dalmation" & CStr(0.65))
        cmbPedigreeDog.Items.Add("Eskimo Dog" & CStr(1.14))
        cmbPedigreeDog.Items.Add("Farm Collie" & CStr(0.95))
        cmbPedigreeDog.Items.Add("GreyHound" & CStr(1.99))
        cmbPedigreeDog.Items.Add("Husky" & CStr(1.85))
        cmbPedigreeDog.Items.Add("Irish Setter" & CStr(0.65))
        cmbPedigreeDog.Items.Add("Jack Russell Terrier" & CStr(1.77))
        cmbPedigreeDog.Items.Add("King Charles Spaniel" & CStr(1.02))
        cmbPedigreeDog.Items.Add("Labrador Retreiver" & CStr(1.74))
        cmbPedigreeDog.Items.Add("Maltese" & CStr(1.47))
        cmbPedigreeDog.Items.Add("Pug" & CStr(1.31))
        cmbPedigreeDog.Items.Add("Rottweiler" & CStr(2.17))
        cmbPedigreeDog.Items.Add("St Bernard" & CStr(1.63))
        cmbPedigreeDog.Items.Add("Tibetan Mastiff" & CStr(1.15))
        cmbPedigreeDog.Items.Add("Working Sheep Dog" & CStr(0.75))
        cmbPedigreeDog.Items.Add("Yorkshire Terrier" & CStr(0.88))
        cmbPedigreeDog.Items.Add("Other" & CStr(1.22))}
```

Comment: DO NOT use the `VisualStudio` tag on questions regarding code which merely happened to be written in Visual Studio

Answer (score 0):

Not the best way, it requires that all your strings in combobox are of the same pattern with same quantity of delimiters.

Example:
If you use instead of `"Boxer" & CStr(0.86)`  something like `"Boxer|" & CStr(0.86)` (added just a | symbol), then you can split this string back like this.

```
line = cmbPedigreeDog.Value
price = CDbl(Split(line, "|")(1))
```

And some explanations:

Each line of text is a container of symbols. Each can be splitted to array with some delimiter. So the line `price = CDbl(Split(line, "|")(1))` can be also written like this:

```
Dim someArray()
line = "Boxer|" & CStr(0.86)

someArray = Split(line, "|")

' after splitting you have two items in array one is "Boxer" and another is "0.86" (which is text)
' if you follow the pattern in each of your combobox options the price always will be the second one
' so you may refer to second item in array, which is number 1

Price = CDbl(someArray(1))
```

**UPDATE**

Another way, as per request in comment. Use two columns combobox. To fill your combobox you have to do following

1 - Go to you ComboBox's properties and set the "ColumnCount" values to 2 (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39422101/adding-two-columns-to-vba-userform-combobox) how to do it).

2 - This is up to you - you may use the binding with prices on a worksheet as like in topic I gave a link in p.1 or change each line on your code to this pattern:

```
With cmbPedigreeDog
    .AddItem ("Boxer")
    .column(1, cbx.ListCount - 1) = 0.86
    .AddItem ("Chihuahua")
    .column(1, cbx.ListCount - 1) = 1.83
    ' and so on
End With
```

3 - To retrieve the price of selected item use such code

```
If cmbPedigreeDog.ListIndex >= 0 Then 
    price = cmbPedigreeDog.List(cbx.ListIndex, 1) 
Else
    MsgBox "item is not chosen"
End If
```

**UPDATE 1**

This answer is for VBA, not for Visual Basic WinForm application. For this try to look for a solution like "Multi Column ComboBox"

Comment: Thanks for the help, would you recommend an easier way ? Even if it requires changing the lot